# how disable gridview header in C#?

Tags: header

How we can disable gridView headers that Users cant click on them!?

actualy I emplemented the selectinChange event gridview. but when user click on the header, it makes error... because I read the current row in selectionChange event. how can I fixed it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the row index for a valid number. If the header is selected the row number is likely to be 0 or -1 (test the actual value yourself). All you then have to do is a simple check in the event handler, something like:

```
if (rowIndex <= 0) // Or some condition you work out for yourself.
    return; // Return because this is the header row.
```

I hope this helps.